# Hadoop (1.1.2) XML processing & re-writing file

Tags: java, xml, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

first question here... and learning hadoop...

I've spent the last 2 weeks trying to understand everything about hadoop, but it seems every hill has a mountain behind it.

Here's the setup:

1. Lots (1 million) of small (<50MB) XML files (Documents formatted into XML).
2. Each file is a record/record
3. Pseudo-distributed Hadoop cluster (1.1.2)
4. using old mapred API (can change, if new API supports what's needed)

I have found XmlInputFormat ("Mahout XMLInputFormat") as a good starting point for reading files, as I can specify the entire XML document as

My understanding is that XmlInputFormat will take care of ensuring each file is it's own record (as 1  tag exists per file/record).

**My issue is this**: I Want to use Hadoop to process every document, search for information, and then, **for each file/record**, re-write or output a new xml document with new xml tag added.

Not afraid of reading and learning, but a skeleton to play with would really help me 'play' and learn hadoop

here is my driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(myDriver.class);
    conf.setJobName("bigjob");
    // Input/Output Directories
    if (args[0].length()==0 || args[1].length()==0) System.exit(-1);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    conf.set("xmlinput.start", "<document>");
    conf.set("xmlinput.end", "</document>");

    // Mapper & Combiner & Reducer
    conf.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    // Input/Output Types
    conf.setInputFormat(XmlInputFormat.class);

    conf.setOutputFormat(?????);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(????);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(????);


    try {
            JobClient.runJob(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say a simple solution would be to use `TextOutputFormat` and then use `Text` as the output key and `NullWritable` as the output value.

`TextOutputFormat` uses a delimiting character to separate the key and value pairs you output from your job. For your requirement, you don't need this arrangement, but you'd just like to output a single body of XML. If you pass null or NullWritable as the output key or value, `TextOutputFormat` will not write the null or the delimiter, just the non-null key or value.

Another approach to using XmlINputFormat would be to use a WholeFileInput (as detailed in Tom White's *Hadoop - The definitive guide*).

Eitherway you'll need to write your mapper to consume the input value Text object (maybe with an XML SAX or DOM parser) and then output the transformed XML as a Text object.